# How to make key value array from multi-dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I want only key value of array from a multidimentional array and key is unique here.

EXAMPLE:

```
Array(
        ['fruit']=> Array
             (
               ['apple']=> red
               ['banana']=> Yellow 
             )
         ['flower']=> Array
             (
               ['rose']=> red
             )
      )
```

ANSWER:

```
Array(
     ['apple']=> red
     ['banana']=> Yellow
     ['rose']=> red
)
```

Comment: Hello! Did you try to solve it by yourself? Could you share your efforts?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your array to achieve your desired output

```
$iteriter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($tree));
$result = [];
foreach ($iteriter as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($result);
```

[RecursiveIteratorIterator](https://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) - Can be used to iterate through recursive iterators.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [apple] => red
    [banana] => Yellow
    [rose] => red
)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8a6fbc6bbd5b756dec6afea6f537a2c671c5b968).

Answer (score 0):

Simply try

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$arr);
```

`print_r($result);`

```
Array
(
 [apple] => red
 [banana] => Yellow
 [rose] => red
)
```